# Follow the shape of the mesh

Tags: mesh

Is it possible to get the studs on the plate and that they follow the shape of the plate?[image]

OK, the studs are on the plate like Markus von Broady said, so done with a curve, now it has to remain so ...
How do I get rid of the curve line without destroying the result and how can I join the studs with the slab, if I do that now the studs disappear?

[image: Studs are now on plate]

[image]

Comment: In this case you could define a curve from the side perspective and apply an array modifier to a plane in the curve mode, and another array in normal mode and set the plane to be an instancer of the studs (without using a plane and an instancer, the studs will be deformed) 

Comment: ...and if he wants to twist it? ;)

Comment: @Chris I'd start with a flat plane (perhaps with what he has now, but add a shape key which I flatten), there subdivide the plane to equal parts, and use vertices to spawn the studs. Though I'm not sure how I'd aquire orientation in this case, so I guess those would have to be faces.

Comment: OK, the studs are on the plate like Markus von Broady said, so done with a curve, now it has to remain so ...
How do I get rid of the curve line without destroying the result and how can I join the studs with the slab, if I do that now the studs disappear?

Comment: Do you mean how to **make instances real**? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html#bpy-ops-object-duplicates-make-real

Comment: If you didn't use an instancer and just array modifiers, then you just have to **apply** these modifiers, e.g. by selecting them **from top to bottom* and pressing CTRL+A. Or you can non-destructively add a boolean cube and use it to remove the studs you don't want.

Comment: OK, I converted the studs to "mesh" and then I could remove the 2 studs and join the studs (CTRL J) with the plate :)